# Delphi: "WriteProcessMemory" is regarded a virus, how to dodge it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to run an exe program from memory. I already found good solutions, but... my virus-chaser wont allow to compile my code. I already tracked down that if I remove the "WriteProcessMemory" callings, the code at least compiles (not running of course...).
It is reported as "modified Win32/Injector.CKX trojan".
But Im surely not writing a virus. The "WriteProcessMemory" function is the problem.

How to run away from the virus-chaser?

Comment: Turn off your antivirus while compiling.

Comment: Or at least configure the antivirus to ignore your compiler.

Comment: and if this program runs on other computers? :)

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? You said the problem occurs when *compiling* your code, not when *running* it. At runtime, writing to another process's memory is not inherently virus-like, especially since Windows itself validates that your app has adequate rights to write to another process's memory before allowing it to happen.

Comment: Do not run away from the scanner, it is actually correct! @Remy, you could have at least googled `Win32/Injector.CKX trojan` before leading the op astray? I'm surprised you did not know about this virus.

Comment: @Johan: You said it yourself. AVs do not trigger on individual instructions, but on signatures that describe particular blocks of code and patterns of behavior. Simply calling `WriteProcessMemory()` is not enough to trigger AVs unless they are being too strict. There are legitimate uses for `WriteProcessMemory()` by itself. Some AVs do report false positives on Delphi and Delphi-written apps for various reasons. I'm not saying Win32/Injector (and Win32/Induc) is not real, but it is also several years old, so AVs have had ample time to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

WriteProcessMemory() is a function often used to inject code into another process - and it also requires enough privileges to work - if you call CreateProcess() you have PROCESS_ALL_PRIVILEGES rights, but if you call OpenProcess() the privileges assigned depends on the process security token, and WriteProcessMemory() may fail.
If you're compiling a program for yourself you may put it into your AV exceptions, but if you're going to deploy it, most AV will probably see the call to WriteProcessMemory() and block it, very few legitimate applications should need to call it.

Comment: Three upvotes make no sense at all. Question talks about AV software interjecting at compile time. Answer talks about runtime.

Comment: If the AV catches it as soon as the executable is created - think about what happens when it is run - you may disable the AV and compile it - but for what? AV performing static code analysis will see it when the exe is created, you may try to use GetProcAddress() to call it but an AV hooking APIs will see it as well. I was also explaining it may not work on any machine as the OP intended - he may have the needed rights on his dev machine, another user may have not them. I've seen enough code requiring too elevate privileges to run without any real need.

Comment: -1, this is nonsense. Virusscanners work with signatures they don't read code and single out instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You <del>may</del> actually have a virus, have you checked for: http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2009/08/19/w32induca-spread-delphi-software-houses/

`Win32/Injector.CKX trojan`, Yep it is the famous Delphi virus.

You need to get a virus cleaner for that one: http://www.sophos.com/en-us/threat-center/threat-analyses/viruses-and-spyware/Mal~Induc-A.aspx

Please apply it and clean up your system.